# Can't set parent using GTK in Python.TypeError: argument parent: Expected Gtk.Window, but got __main__.function

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to make a GTK program that brings up other child windows, but I can't seem to get set_transient_for to work.

The window I'm having trouble with is called "about" for now. I am trying to set the window under __init__ as its parent, but when I try to use the "About" menu, I get:

```
TypeError: argument parent: Expected Gtk.Window, but got __main__.function
```

Here's how I made the window.

```
class App(Gtk.Window):
def __init__(self):
    ## Create window. ##
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Simple Updater")
    self.set_border_width(5)
    self.set_resizable(False)
```

I used uimanager to create some menus and packed them in a grid. Here's how I call my about window.

```
## Menu functions ##

def add_about_actions(self, action_group):
    action_group.add_actions([
    ("About", None, "About"), 
    ("About...", None, "About...", None, None, Windows.About)
    ])
```

I created another class for my child windows. Here's where I try to set the parent as window __init__.

```
class Windows(Gtk.Window):
    def About(self):
        about = Gtk.Window(title="About")
        about.set_border_width(10)
        about.set_resizable(False)
        about.set_transient_for(__init__)
```

I also tried:

```
about.set_transient_for(App.__init__)
```

And here's how I set up my GTK loop.

```
top = App()
top.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
top.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I've tried to figure out what's going on for several hours now with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to use the object itself for the method not `__init__` e.g `dialog.set_transient_for(parent)`

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work. Just realized that top is the object, not \_\_init\_\_ and I feel incredibly stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question of: [GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29883211/1833602)

You need to pass the variable holding the main window object.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was a duplicate. Thanks for the link.

Comment: No problem. Duplicates are not a bad thing. People choose different wordings for similar problems.