# GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged

Tags: c, gtk

I have a C program which uses Gtk. What I'm trying to do is basically have a file chooser dialog pop up to allow the user to pick a file. However, whenever the dialog opens, it always prints

```
Gtk-Message: 21:39:14.067: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I tried to use `gtk_window_set_transient_for` as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883211/gtkdialog-mapped-without-a-transient-parent) suggested, but this didn't change anything.

My code:

```
// window is defined else where as a GtkWidget *window;

GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Pick a file", GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, "Open", 0, NULL);
gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(dialog), GTK_WINDOW(window));
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
```

Comment: I will guess it is something in your code itself. Could you post an MCVE showing this problem?

Comment: @theGtknerd sure give me a minute

Comment: @theGtknerd, never mind, for some reason window was NULL. I fixed it. thanks