# electron app crashes on select input type file

Tags: javascript, iframe, electron

I rendered a full website in electron app using iframe.
When I try to choose an image to upload, app crashes with below message

> Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

This happens only in Linux ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883211/gtkdialog-mapped-without-a-transient-parent)

Comment: no, this won't solve my issue

Comment: Can you confirm that the app terminates? I see that exact message whenever any dialog is opened (on Ubuntu), but the app doesn't terminate. For me, it's just a warning.

Comment: yeah app terminates